# I can't load GUI on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: nvidia, gui

Once I rebooted my laptop, and then it has never loaded in GUI mode after that. I can use only tty 1-6, tried reinstall gdm3, lightdm, sddm, purged nvidia drivers and reinstalled. Always as I try to start gui( startx, xinit, systemctl start gdm3) it appears for only severel seconds and crashes. Log file in Xorg is clear, without (EE). I also reinstalled ubuntu-gnome-desktop, installed new 4.18.0-16-generic, reinstalled Xorg. Nothing. Is there someone, who can help?

Comment: You did so many wrong things, that it would be the only feasible option to re-install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is not simple to solve. There is a lot of knowledge 
about X necessary to solve this kind of situation. I suggest the following 
procedure to start a diagnosis:

1 - If it is a driver issue, then you will see no graphic window showing. 
If you see some graphical, then the driver is working and the problem is 
other (I think this is your case). If it is a graphic card issue, do 
`lspci` and see what VGA board you have and try to see the best driver 
to that. You cited that your video board is Nvidia, so usually install 
the package "nvidia-driver" will do the trick. When finished, 
`modprobe nividia` as root, or reboot the system. The driver probably 
will be inserted at boot (`lsmod | grep nv` as root will show it).

2 - Try to log-in as user and simply run `Xorg` without any 
parameters. This should show you a grey pattern screen. If this happens, 
the Xorg is working (without a Window Manager X and Xorg does nothing). 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> can shutdown Xorg. Or <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (to -<kbd>F6</kbd>) to change 
to a text terminal `ps` and `kill` Xorg manually.

3 - Do `cat` to the file /etc/X11/default-display-manager. It will show 
the default display manager, usually the login manager (lightdm, gdm, 
kdm, etc. ). If it is not installed or points to the wrong executable, 
then the display will crash and X will close. It looks like you problem, 
so  see if the value is right and and correct it if needed.

I am using Xfce and so the value in default-display-manager for me is:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

In your case it could be /usr/sbin/gdm3 (or something like that).

4 - The command /usr/bin/startx is a script. There are a lot of user 
files referenced by that script. See if one of that has some weird 
value. Usually the files are in user directory and are .x(something) or 
.X(something) . Be carefull, because there are .x(something) files not 
related to Xorg.

If you have Gnome installed, you can try to start it using `startgnome`
script (startgnome3, startkde or startxfce4, or something like this 
depending on what you have installed). I remember the graphical interfaces 
are packed with this scripts to help. If the interface enters, the problem 
is with the login manager or other file.

The config files for X are in the `/etc/X11` directory. Special attention to 
`/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`  and `/etc/X11/Xsession` .

If there are X or Xorg errors when you enter the user space, you can see 
the errors in user directory in the file .xsession-errors .

This text does not show how to solve your problem, but is a start to 
diagnose it.

Graphic interfaces are very complex, there are a lot of problems that are 
system wide (your problem for instance) and a lot of problems that are user 
space specific (configuration files in user space problems, Display Manager 
behavior because user space config problems and so on).

Different of many commercial software, Linux enables you to dig the 
problem til the scripts (and til the source code if you really need). 
The task is huge, but do not get discouraged by that. You can learn 
everything that happens in your system if you want. But to do that 
you need to be pacient and stubborn enough to study, try and try 
again til it works.

I hope you can find the solution of your problem.

Ric.